# Jsoup selector - How to select all <p> elements inside <div> element, except for the last <p> element?

Tags: java, android, jsoup

there is a bunch of html elements as following:

```
<div class="abc">
   <p>a</p>
   <p>b</p>
   <p>c</p>
   <p>x</p>
</div>
```

I want to select a, b, c without x. I'm looking forward to receiving your support. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use css pseudo-classes `not` and `last-child`.

```
Elements e = doc.select(".abc p:not(:last-child)")
```

Comment: Done :). Thanks for your help.